# Can not plot predictedvalues with SARIMA

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima, sarimax

I am bulding SARIMA time series with `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax` beacuse pmdarima doesn't install. My data has 44 observation 10 years every quarter. My target is to predict next 1 or 2 years. Could anyone give idea what I need to pot the prediction. I am not proficient in Python but I think there is kinf of missunderstanding between my quarterly data and the desired prediction. I compile algorityhm from towardsdatascience, articles from here and youtube.
After evaluating P,D,Q, m parameters with min AIC and fit the model this is the result - can't plot the predict steps [image: predicted values missing]
I made 2 columns - dates and GVA - gross added value I am looking for [Data set is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4rjk59faqbl3i5/bg_gva_sarima.csv?dl=0)

If someone could help..

[Google collab notebook is here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15_YboweAZvE8tfM88_KDkUSQXv49KtrF#scrollTo=lgIHeSHFhmnl)
[Dataset I have collected is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4rjk59faqbl3i5/bg_gva_sarima.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data is prepared (setting index right, stationarizing etc.), I usually do as follows:

```
model2 = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df['x'], order=(0, 1, 3), seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 4))
res2 = model2.fit()
pred_uc2 = res2.get_forecast(steps=12) # note here the usage of steps ahead and get_forecast
pred_ci2 = pred_uc2.conf_int()
ax = df['x'].plot(label = OB, figsize=(14, 8)) # test data
pred_uc2.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label=FC) $ prediction
ax.fill_between(pred_ci2.index, # confidence intervals
                pred_ci2.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci2.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'll accept your GREAT recommendation! The number 3 in the range [0,24,3] also helped as follow 
`new_dates=[df.index[-1]+DateOffset(months=x) for x in range(0,24,3)]` 
Could I ask u if I am not braking the rules - are u recommending these number for my model (0, 1, 3), seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 4) beacuse I am really looking for someone to approve it

Comment: I'm sorry, this was just a code snippet from something I was doing recently to give you an idea about how it works. The ARIMA model does not fit your specific data. For parameter search you may use `pmdarima` package or grid search, provided you have enough [theory background](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411home.htm).

Comment: It's OK. I couldn't install `pmdarima` - I reinstalled jupyter NB twice updated all libraries - but Nothing. I'll read again the theory you preovded which, I used till now.  Does my model look reasonable if you have time only [G collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15_YboweAZvE8tfM88_KDkUSQXv49KtrF#scrollTo=irl6prw0Bftq)